# Setting environment variable in Windows 11, using 'set' and 'export', but didn't work

Tags: node.js, windows, environment-variables, windows-11

I am currently using Windows11, and working on the node.js project.
In the index.js, I am trying to read the current env variable by

```
console.log(`NODE_ENV: ${process.env.NODE_EVN}`);
```

And I set the environment variable in the terminal(under admin) by:

```
set NODE_ENV=production
```

However, the output is also undefined when I run the index.js
I understand in the mac or linux, setting the env variable is using 'export'
So I also try to use git bash to set the environment variable by:

```
export NODE_ENV=production
```

This also doesn't work; I am really confused about how to set the environment variable on windows11.

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables of the type you're setting are private to each process. When a process starts a new, child, process it normally gives that new process a copy of it environment variables. An env var you set in one process is not visible to a different, already running, process. However, Windows also has the concept of "system variables" which are global. Google "windows global variables" for a large number of explanations how to define such variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can set environment variable in the Windows 11 Powershell using:

```
$env:NODE_ENV='production'
```